# EJB JAX-WS Web Service authentication and authorization

Tags: ejb, jax-ws, basic-authentication

How can I authenticate with HTTP Basic, via the application server domain/secure realm, using a Session Bean published as a `@WebService`?

In a Web project one could use `web.xml` to map Roles to Groups, but I have no idea how to do it in a EJB-JAR project. I don't think it can be done with `ejb-jar.xml`.

Sample code, which works fine without the roles annotations:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(portName="RestrictedServicePort")
@DeclareRoles(value = "Administrators")
public class RestrictedServiceBean {

    @RolesAllowed(value = "Administrators")
    public String restrictedOperation() {
        return "Secret information";        
    }

}
```

Error:

```
<faultstring>[EJB:010160]Security Violation: User: '&lt;anonymous>' has insufficient permission to access EJB: type=&lt;ejb>
```

Basic Credentials Header:

`Authorization: Basic d2VibG9naWM6d2VsY29tZTE=`

I suspect it must be done via vendor-specific configuration. I am using WebLogic 10.3.6, Java EE 5 / EJB 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding the role mapping as it is done in any web module, but using the proprietary *weblogic-ejb-jar.xml*, as follows:

```
<wls:security-role-assignment>
    <wls:role-name>Administrators</wls:role-name>
    <wls:principal-name>myweblogicgroup</wls:principal-name>
</wls:security-role-assignment>
```

The "myweblogicgroup" is the group created in the WebLogic security realm for which the system user used to authenticated to the web service is associated.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621155/how-to-set-up-weblogic-10-3-3-security-for-jax-ws-web-services) helped me.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic Auth via Policy**

From the [v10 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/webservices/ConfigureWSPolicyFile.html):

> A Web service can have zero or more WS-Policy files associated with
>   it. WS-Policy files follow the guidelines of the WS-Policy
>   specification. WebLogic Server uses WS-Policy files to specify the
>   details of the message-level security (digital signatures and
>   encryption) and reliable messaging capabilities of a Web service. You
>   can attach a WS-Policy file to a Web service endpoint, which means
>   that the policy assertions apply to all the operations of a Web
>   service endpoint. You can also attach a WS-Policy file to an
>   operation, which means that the policy assertions apply only to the
>   specific operation. In addition, you can attach a WS-Policy file to
>   the inbound or outbound SOAP message, or both.

It would appear you can [attach a basic auth policy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13713/transport.htm#WSSOV246) to your service:

```
<sp:TransportToken>
  <wsp:Policy>
    <sp:HttpBasicAuthentication/>
  </wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportToken>
```

You can apply this custom policy via the administrative console via the steps outlined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/webservices/ConfigureWSPolicyFile.html) or you can consider referencing one of the [Oracle-preconfigured policies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/b32511/policies.htm#CHDEDBJD).

---

**Mapping Roles to Groups**

The WebLogic (v12) [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24972/annotations.htm#EJBAD310) mentions the following when discussing usage of `@RolesAllowed` in an EJB:

> You can also use the annotation to explicitly declare roles that are implicitly declared if you use the @RolesAllowed annotation on the class or a method of the class.
>
> You create security roles in WebLogic Server using the Administration Console. For details, see "[Manage Security Roles](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24401/taskhelp/security/ManageSecurityRoles.html)" in the Oracle WebLogic Server Administration Console Help.

The [Manage Security Roles](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24401/taskhelp/security/ManageSecurityRoles.html) section continues on to discuss `scoped roles.`

> You can then create a scoped role for a specific EJB that contains highly sensitive business logic. When you create a policy for the EJB, you can specify that only the scoped role can access the EJB.

More information on managing scoped roles is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24401/taskhelp/security/DefineScopedRoles.html).

Comment: Your answer does not relate to the HTTP authentication aspect of my question. My problem is that, even with roles declared in the session bean and created in the AS, WebLogic does not authenticate with my Basic credentials. What is the purpose of publishing an EJB with JAX-WS if one cannot use application server features over it, like, simple HTTP Basic authentication? I would expect it to be integrated.

Comment: apologies, I keyed on your question's statement on mapping roles to groups.  I'll update the answer with more specifically on basic auth.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I had no success applying your suggestions in the very few attempts that I made. I was able to secure my Web Service using the answer I just posted here.